# 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have created a new springboot project using the gradle - kotlin and Springboot 3.1.0(Snapshot) with the java version 17. There are no changes in this fresh project. When I run this project I am getting this error.-

```
***************************

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

here is my build.gradle.kts file -

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.20"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.8.20"
}

group = "com.example.op2"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am trying to run the new project but unable to run the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency in build.gradle.kts:-

```
runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
```